# Only validate when an attribute is present with Rails and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, image-uploading

Here's the code I have

```
class FactSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

And the uploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

This is all good, but the problem I'm facing is that in this scenario it's optional for a user to supply an image, so I don't want to be seeing the following validation error if they don't supply one

```
Image You are not allowed to upload "" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png
```

What's the best way to only validate/mount the uploader if the image is present?

Comment: This is proper validator, but, in which case don't you wish to skip the message, I just haven't seen that case...

Comment: When you wish to assign non image it lead to the errors is being added, just assign nothing value to the field.

Answer (score 1):

In your FactSheet  model, you could something like this:

```
   validates :attachment, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)\Z}i,
    message: 'image must be a GIF, JPEG, PNG format'
   }
```

Comment: That's great, but I'd like to be able to using the ImageUploader class if possible. Could I possibly run "mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader" conditionally?

Comment: why would you try to run it conditionally? when you can do something which you can get away with simple `allow_blank: true` in your model..Also as far as I know, haven't seen anyone doing it that way.